# Is this a hint/Easter egg in the opening titles of this Watchmen episode?

Tags: dc, watchmen

At the beginning of every episode of HBO's *Watchmen*, the series title is shown in different forms/contexts.

In particular, in the eighth episode "A God walks into Abar", the word *Watchmen* is depicted as a neon sign, which turns from yellow to blue; these two colors, of course, are respectively signatures of the whole series and of Dr. Manhattan, the main character of this episode.

Eventually the "M" turns off, turning the word into a "WATCH EN" if one considers only the lighted letters:

[image: The neon blue sign with the M not lighting up so it reads "WATCH EN"]

Considering that this series, pretty much like the comic book which is based on, is full of hints, subtle references and <strike>Easter</strike> eggs, I'm convinced that this should have some sort of significance and that it is not some random visual effect.

Is "Watch en" a hint to pay attention to something (i.e. "watch this")? But in this case, what is "en" supposed to mean?
Is the unlighted "M" a nod to

> Dr. Manhattan "turning off" in this episode, losing his powers and becoming a "normal" human thanks to the device given to him by Adrian Veidt?

Is this documented somewhere? Is there some official explanation about this?